# Trying to store numbers with return but I get undfined?

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript and I decided to try and create a calculator. My current functions give each of my divs with the class "number" an ID correspondent to the number the div represents in my calculator.

What I'm trying to achieve with the numberOne function is to store the value of the div clicked inside the variable newNum, as in if div#4 is clicked, 4 gets stored inside newNum, but I get an undefined and I'm not sure why..

```
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number')

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i].id =+ (i + 1);

    if (numbers[i].className == 'number') {
        numbers[i].onclick = numberOne;
    }
}

function numberOne() {
    let firstNum = this.id;
    console.log(firstNum);
    return firstNum;
}

let newNum = newFunction();
```

/* --------- fixed --------- */

```
let numbers = document.querySelectorAll('.number')
let newNum;

for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i].id =+ (i + 1);

    if (numbers[i].className == 'number') {
        numbers[i].onclick = numberOne;
    }
}

function numberOne() {
    let firstNum = this.id;
    console.log(firstNum);
    newNum = firstNum;
    return firstNum;
}
```

Comment: `this.id` what it is refereed to ?

Comment: What is `newNum` and `newFunction()`?

Comment: @connexo sorry that's a typo, newFunction() is meant to be numberOne(). newNum is the variable im trying to store the numbers in.

Comment: @lucumt It refers to the ID of the the clicked "numbers"

Comment: `=+` is not a thing.

Comment: What melpomene meant was Javascript uses: '+='; e.g. x += y; is equivalent to x = x + y;

Comment: @melpomene I see, thank you